# Extract values from a data frame in one line

Tags: r

I have a data frame with xy coordinates of a polygon, such as

```
head(df)
         x        y
1 -80.59264 40.88406
2 -80.50539 40.91076
3 -80.41909 40.93284
4 -80.32967 40.94047
5 -80.24228 40.93894
6 -80.16811 40.93434
```

I try to extract it to obtain something like this:

```
df
(-80.59264 40.88406, -80.50539 40.91076, -80.41909 40.93284, -80.32967 40.94047, -80.24228 40.93894, -80.16811 40.93434...)
```

i.e. each line is separated by a comma and column values with a space.

This is possible to do this in R?

Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps use `paste`

```
do.call(paste, c(df, collapse = ", "))
```